# span of symmetrically truncated symmetric random variables

Tags: pr.probability

If $X_i$ are symmetric independent random variables, is  $\vert \sum X_i I_{\vert X_i \vert < N_i}\vert $ stochastically smaller than $\vert \sum X_i \vert$ ?  Is it comparable in any way which would guarantee the former was stochastically bounded if the latter was ?  The motivating example is i.i.d. cauchy, when the convex hull of the r.v.s consists entirely of Cauchys, but can the convex hull of the truncated guys contain stochastically unbounded guys ?  (The $X_i$ are stochastically bounded if there is $S(x),  S(x) \rightarrow 0 $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ with $\mathbb P(\vert X_i \vert > x  ) <  S(x) \; \forall i$)

Comment: Did you mean to take the modulus of the last expression in the first sentence?

Comment: You can deduce a lot from Hoffman Jorgensen's inequality (or Rosenthal's inequality, which follows from it, by getting moment estimates for large $p$ and looking at the asymptotics as $p\to \infty$).  Look at
the paper

http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.aop/1008956339


 by Hitczenko and Montgomery-Smith and references therein, especially the paper by Klass and Nowicki.

Comment: The paper is

MEASURING THE MAGNITUDE OF SUMS OF INDEPENDENT RANDOM VARIABLES
Annals Prob. 29 no.1, 447-466,

by P. Hitczenko and S. Montgomery-Smith.

Comment: yes, I'll make that edit if it lets me.

Comment: I think second order stochastic dominance might be what I'm looking for.